# Javascript: How to get callback's parameters

Tags: javascript, closures, javascript-objects, anonymous-function

I'm trying to somewhat replicate the functionality of forEach so that I can understand it better. In forEach you can pass it in an anonymous function with a parameter 'item' and then it would give you the items in the array. So how is this done exactly? Below I have a function print where I call another function a with an anonymous function as parameter. So how can I extract the parameter called 'param' from the anonymous function and use it in a's definition.

```
function print() {
  var param = 'param1'
  a(function(param) {
    console.log('execute a')
  })
}

function a(fn) {
  //how can i access the fn's parameter list here?
  //execute fn and do something with its parameter
  fn()

}

print()
```

What I'm trying to accomplish: Run the function "a" and execute the anonymous function passed into it along with its parameters

Answer (score 1):

You're completely misunderstanding parameters.

Your callback is a function.  Its parameters are passed by the code that calls it (in `a()`), just like any other function.

If you want to pass a parameter to `a()`, you should pass it like any other parameter.

---

The fact that your callback's parameter happens to have the same name as a local variable is completely irrelevant.

Comment: SLaks, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying the code above is wrong and should not be done that way?

Comment: @user1142130: Your question doesn't really make sense.  You need to understand how parameters and functions work.  What are you trying to do?